# Django: Raw SQL Query with parameterized parameters

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-injection

I'm trying to test the vulnerabilities of SQL injection using the Manager's raw() function in Django. I'm using SQLite as the backend database.
I have tried the following two functions for showing the values of the Person Model that I have created.

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('unsafe/<str:user_name>', views.unsafe_get_users, name='unsafe_get_users'),
path('safe/<str:user_name>', views.safe_get_users, name='safe_get_users'),
]
```

#### models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
age = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + " " + str(self.age)
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person

def unsafe_get_users(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # sqli using raw
    user_name = kwargs['user_name']
    users = Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM member_list_person WHERE name = %s' % user_name)
    
    return HttpResponse(users)

def safe_get_users(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # uses parameterized query
    user_name = kwargs['user_name']
    users = Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM member_list_person WHERE name = %s', [user_name])
    
    return HttpResponse(users)
```

The Person Model has two fields, namely name and age.

As for the unsafe_get_users function, the column data are displayed successfully but for the safe_get_users function, nothing shows up on the server page.

I have tried printing len(users), which shows the number of data in the returned RawQuerySet, but for the second one it returns 0 (empty query).

Why does unsafe_get_users function return the data as expected but not the safe_get_users function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not use raw queries in the first place, this is simply `Person.objects.filter(name=user_name)`.

Comment: Furthermore, exactly *what* `user_name` did you use? If it contains a space, for example, then this can alter the semantics of the query.

Comment: In very rare cases ( probably never), you may use raw queries. It's much better practice to just write a database view and just put that in the model with manage=false. It really depends on your use case but the query you show is very simple for some DB specific stuff that you can't do with django ORM.

Comment: And remember you break an important design principle in software development : Separation of concerns. At least put the SQL in different `.py` file

Comment: @J.Cunningham you can try this : `f"SELECT * FROM member_list_person WHERE name = '{user_name}';"`.

Comment: @AjayLingayat but is that using parameterized query?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I typed in 'john' for the user_name in the url parameter. I had created the object name= 'john', age='20' in advance. So the url was localhost:8080/member_list/safe/'john'. I know Django ORM should be used but I wanted to see if raw queries that are parameterized work safely too. But why is it returning an empty queryset?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I figured that I had to type localholst:8080/member_list/safe/john (without the single quotes) and it worked! but putting john or 1=1 doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @J.Cunningham You can use it this way `Person.objects.raw(f"SELECT * FROM member_list_person WHERE name = '{user_name}';")`.